# use non angular dependency in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use jszip in an angular service but it is not written using angular.  I've looked at the answers to this question [Inject non-angular JS libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295559/inject-non-angular-js-libraries) and this question [How to make lodash work with Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862119/how-to-make-lodash-work-with-angular-js) which are both trying to get lodash to work in angular.  I've tried creating a module like this

```
angular.module('jszip', [])
    .constant('_', window._)
    .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope._ = window._;
    });
```

And injecting it into a service like this

```
app.factory('FileService', ['Restangular', 'DeviceService', 'jszip',
    function FileUploadService(Restangular, DeviceService, jszip) {
    // ....
}]);
```

but I get this error

```
angular.js:10147 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: jszipProvider <- jszip <- FileService
```

Also I'm assuming the underscore is something specific for lodash? In general how do I add a non angular dependency?

Comment: You didn't define jszip service, You defined jszip module.

Comment: I created a jszip module because I thought that was the method to be taken to use jszip in a service

Comment: It looks like you're confusing modules with services. You can't inject a module. You can load it and then inject its service. Module's name is `jszip`. And service's name is `_`.

Comment: thank you, I get the same unknown provider exception when I inject '_' because my browser is not loading the folder that holds this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My module wasn't loading because I wasn't including the file containing the code in any of my html files like this

```
<script src="app/main/export-import/export-import.service.js"></script>
```

This is also how you include non angular dependencies

```
<script src="export/libs/jszip/jszip.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem it's not the `$rootScope._ = window._;`. Probably the module file is not getting loaded, and when you try to inject into FileService, he dosen't reconize.

Try to aceess the file in the browser inspector